# Sybunt and Lybunt Report fields

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

I'm confused why Organization Name and Prefix are in the Lybunt report but not in the Sybunt report.  They both have

```
'fields' => $this->getBasicContactFields(),
```

which I thought included these fields.  Maybe I'm missing something.

I can quickly add Organization with this:

```
'organization_name' => array(
            'title' => ts('Organization'),
          ),
```

but I'm unclear how to add the prefix_id and convert it to the correct output (Mr., Mrs., etc)

```
   'prefix_id' => array(
            'title' => ts('Prefix'),
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Drupal 7.51, Civicrm 4.7.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed that the correct solution is to work within `getBasicContactFields()`, but since your question is a good one with a more general application:

When you add organization name and prefix, you're doing so by adding them to the class's `_columns` property.  As you note, this doesn't look up "pseudoconstants", such as converting prefix_id to a prefix.

That happens in the `alterDisplay` method toward the bottom of the same file.  Here's a good example in the Lybunt report of using a pseudoconstant lookup to convert the gender ID to a gender:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/Lybunt.php#L719

Hopefully this example is what you need; otherwise feel free to comment/update the question!

Comment: Thanks Jon!  That worked perfectly and is going to help so much moving forward in trying to build out custom reports.